# git-svn: preserving merges across two different git-svn repos

Tags: git, svn, merge, workflow

We have been using a workflow at work for several months where SVN developers create SVN fix branches which are merged into an integration branch using git and committed back into SVN, a merge at a time, with dcommit. In this workflow, there has been a single git-svn repo doing all the merge work.

This workflow has worked pretty well and the git merges are usually faithfully preserved in the original git-svn repo.

However, now we have decided to spread the merging workload across a number of users, each of which has their own git-svn repo. Unfortunately, we are now finding that merges performed by one git-svn user sometimes (but not always) appear like single parent commits in the git-svn repo of the other user instead of looking like two parent merges.

Loss of the merge history plays havoc with history analysis and causes unnecessary merge conflicts since git can no longer identify the correct merge-base, something it could do if merges parents had been preserved across all repositories.

Does anyone have any practices that help to avoid the circumstances that cause the merge history to be corrupted in one or more git-svn repos that sync with a common SVN repo?

Comment: I have been using git-svn for quite some time and did not meet this problem.Maybe due to I follow a simple workflow. Are the "branches" you mentioned all git branch ? You may give more detail of your workflow.

Comment: The branches are SVN branches. The git merges are always between the two git commits corresponding to the tips of two SVN branches and are always immediately dcommit'd to SVN after a successful merge.

As I say, this has been working pretty well, when I was the one doing all the integration merges. However, now a colleague has started to take on some of the merging workload and I sometimes lose the 2nd parent of merges he does and vice versa - he sometimes loses the 2nd parent of merges that I do.

Comment: BTW: We have 341 SVN tags and 560 SVN branches. As a result the svn:mergeinfo property values at the tip of the integration branch are quite complex and large.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what causes the problem, but I have found that an acceptable workaround is to recreate the merges in git by use of grafts as per the technique described here:

[Fixing SVN Merge History in Git Repositories](http://blog.agavi.org/post/16865375185/fixing-svn-merge-history-in-git-repositories)

although I haven't bothered with the filter branch yet as I am not completely convinced it plays nice with the svn rev maps that git-svn uses to track the mapping between SVN and git commits.